# Что не так с методами getCountTheSameFirstName и getCountTheSameLastName?

Tags: java

Требования:

1. Программа не должна выводить текст на экран.
2. Программа не должна считывать значения с клавиатуры.
3. Метод createMap() должен создавать и возвращать словарь Map с типом элементов String, String состоящих из 10 записей по принципу «Фамилия» - «Имя».
4. Метод getCountTheSameFirstName() должен возвращать число людей у которых совпадает имя.
5. Метод getCountTheSameLastName() должен возвращать число людей у которых совпадает фамилия.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет это Вы расскажите нам, что не так с этими методами :-) Желательно выбрать один из них и расписать как можно подробнее и с примерами что он делает не так.

Comment: Метод getCountTheSameFirstName должен выводить количество одинаковых значений мапа, но , видимо, я что-то сделал не так и он этого не делает или делает неправильно

Comment: Расскажите что значит делает неправильно с примерами ввода и вывода, например: ввожу имена: «Вася, Кеша, Shdbd, Shdbd», метод возвращает -14, хотя должен 1. Еще, приложите код в виде текста, чтобы его можно было скопировать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как-то  так:

```
public static int getCountTheSameFirstName(
        Map<String, String> map,
        String name) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String item : map.values()) {
        if (item.equals(name)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;

}

public static int getCountTheSameLastName(
        Map<String, String> map,
        String lastName) {
    return map.containsKey(lastName) ? 1 : 0;
}
```